# 18th and 19th century skeptics of imaginary numbers?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

Complex numbers were used in as early as the 16th century to solve cubic equations, but they didn't gain wide acceptance until the late 18th and early 19th century. What is the reason for the 200 year delay in accepting imaginary numbers? Were there any famous mathematicians (or philosophers) that renounced imaginary numbers, and why?

Comment: See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5904/were-complex-number-first-considered-of-limited-usefulness

Comment: Because [Argand gave them a geometric interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Robert_Argand) only in 1813 (actually, Wessell did it already in 1799, but his paper went unnoticed). This turned them into something tangible, before that they were seen as nebulous fictions in algebraic manipulations. Gauss wrote "*the true metaphysics of √-1 is elusive*" as late as 1825, but his 1831 endorsement and use of them in number theory finally broke the ice. See [Cut-the-Knot history essay](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/HistoricalRemarks.shtml) on de Morgan's renouncement.